# Unexpected Border-Left:none on one element of menu?

Tags: css, css-selectors

On this site I am doing the template for:

http://questionlounge.com/

The "Latest Questions" menu tab has a strange element style added to it that is `border-left:none`;

I can't see how it gets there as the CSS and markup is fine.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have a script in your page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tabs li:eq(0) a").css("border-left", "none");
   .....
   }
```

i think this is the culprit

Comment: Lol I was looking at that code and because of the large gap between the top part and bottom part I never even scrolled down to see that. Guess I should have made more use of Ctrl+F. Thanks guys/gals.

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery $(document).ready() function which does this:

```
   $(".tabs li:eq(0) a").css("border-left", "none");
```